# How to change Google Application name

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am working on a simple (for the moment) Google API application that reads Google Analytics data from a customer's Analytics account.  'm completely new to the Google API, so I started out using a single customer's Google log-in, with their permission, and got the application working that way.  That is, I was signed into Google on my machine using their account, and ran the app from my local machine using a PHP script and callback page that were both on my local server.  It worked.

Now I want to generalize the app so I can use it with any customer that has an Analytics account.  To that end, I did the following:

- signed out of the first customer's Google account
- signed into an old Google Developer account that I have
- picked a project in this old account of mine, changed its name, and created a new secrets.json  file for it.
- copied the working app's PHP files (this is all done in PHP) to new filenames and set it up to use the new secrets.json file and callback file name.
- wiped my browser's cache to get rid of any lingering traces of the old app.

I did not change any other code in the app files -- it's working, I figured, so why change it?

Problem: When I run the new app and it contacts Google for permission to access the customer's Analytics data, Google reacts as if the call is coming from the old app.  It then throws a security error because the redirect URI in the access request doesn't match the redirect URI on record for the old app.

I've looked everywhere I can think of, and I can't find any way to reset the app name, so that Google will see this as the new app, not the old one.  What am I doing wrong?  What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) and navigate to the credentials page, find the Client ID you wish to update and click "Edit Settings." Then change the redirect URI to match that of your application. The  [Hello Analytics API: PHP quickstart for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php) should give you all the steps to setup/update an application settings.